# How to read second and last words from each line in C

Tags: c

I have a file with data like this

{0   /*Data1*/               , 0x00,      0,  0xFF},

{1   /*data2*/               , 0x00,      0,  0xFF},

{2   /*data3*/               , 0x00,      0,  0xFF},

{3   /*data4*/               , 0x00,      0,  0xFF},
...

I want to print only the second and last column of each line. Below is the code I worked on. Its printing the whole line. How to edit  to print only the second and last column of each line.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

int main ()
{       
    char filename[] = "file.txt"; 

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file!= NULL)     
    {                           
        char line[128];                 

        while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, file)!= NULL)
        {                                           
            fputs ( line,stdout);                           
        }                                                       
        fclose(file);                           
    }                                               
    else                    
    {                               
        perror(filename);                   
    }                                           


    getch();                    

    return 0;                       
}
```

Please Help!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is this C or C++? The answer varies greatly...

Comment: Look at the `strtok()` function, it might help.

Comment: PLZ PLZ no conio.h

Comment: It looks like you're only trying to print the whole line in the above code. What steps have you taken to try to break it up? You might want to take a look at `scanf()`.

Comment: Please remove tabs before pasting code.

Comment: It is in C.. I want to split the line using scanf, but I dont know how can I break it to get word 2 and last word.

Comment: You could use awk: `cat data1 | awk -F, '{print $(NF-1) }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sscanf()](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/sscanf.html) should do the trick.

It uses a format string just like printf(), then reads the values into variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, c, d, e;
    char b[101] = "";
    char filename[] = "file.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[128];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
            sscanf(line, "{%d %100s , %x, %d, %x}", &a, b, &c, &d, &e);
            printf("%d %X\n", d, e);
        }
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        perror(filename);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked except for printing the hexadecimal, its printing 40 for all.. nywz thanks...

Comment: {1 /Data1/ , 0x00, 0, 0x1F}

prints "0 1F\n"

Do you have any more example input data?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is formatted this way: {0 /Data1/ , 0x00, 0, 0xFF} u can search the bracket at the end of the data line.

Example(not the full solition)

```
char data[] = "{0 /Data1/ , 0x00, 0, 0xFF},"

//find the back bracket position

int i=0;
while( i < strlen(data) && data[i]!='}')
 i++;

if(i<strlen(data))
 bracketposition = i;
```

When you find the position of bracket rewind for word size (if it is not standart search for the whitespace) and read the value between this two positions (whitespace position and bracket position)